# how can i create dynamic link that will work in all controllers

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc, url

I have ProfileController that have to getMapping by SpringSecurityUsername.

```
@Controller
public class ProfileController {

    @GetMapping("/profile/{profileName}")
    public String showProfilePage(@PathVariable("profileName")String profileName){
        return "profile";
    }
}
```

and i have dynamic link like this in a header of site so user can always click on it

```
<a th:href="@{/profile/{name}(name=${username})}">profile</a>
```

So if I want use link i have to find every time User in each classController

```
@Controller
public class SearchController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String showIndexPage(Model model){
        User user = userService.findUserByUsername(someNameFromSecurityHandler);
        model.addAttribute("username",user.getUsername());
        return "index";
    }
```

Every time I have to find User for this link. What i have to do if i want optimize this thing. Because I think that evry time find User in db its bad idea, because often people will not use profile page and its just extra costs of time. And i have create this code in every controll class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using Spring Security for securing your MVC application (you say something about SpringSecurityUsername but its not clear).

If the above is true, then your Authentication Principal will already be included in the session (assuming you logged in already). You simply need to access it as follows:

```
@GetMapping("/")
public String showIndexPage(Model model, Authentication auth){
    String username = auth.getName();
    ...
}
```

Also, you can access spring security details directly from thymeleaf rather than setting it from the controller (Untested, but is possible https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity). You will need the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Then, in thymeleaf you can do the following:

```
<a th:href="@{|/profile/${#authentication.name}|}">profile</a>
```